# ul is gone after clicking menu button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Currently learning JS and today I tried to combine my works and it doesn't work really well.
There are two parts of this.
・Menu button that can expand it's width and height when clicked
・An interactive window that can move left and right depend on which button is clicked
The problem is when I click the menu button and expand the menu and then click it again to put it back it it's original size, the interactive window is gone and moved to the left.
What am I missing ? Is there a way to fix this ?

I've put together the code in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Thaldrin94/ur6x5nzb/12/)
I've put the code bellow.
Thanks in advance.

```js
// JS for Menu
document.getElementById("menu_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var open1 = document.getElementById("opened_menu");
  var open2 = document.getElementById("menu_background");

  if (open1.style.display == "none") {
    open1.style.display = "block";
    open2.style.width = '100%';
    open2.style.height = '100vh';
  } else {
    open1.style.display = "none";
    open2.style.width = '0%';
    open2.style.height = '0vh';
  }

})

// JS for Interactive Window
let trans = {
  nextIn: 'animate__fadeInLeft',
  nextOut: 'animate__fadeOutRight',
  prevIn: 'animate__fadeInRight',
  prevOut: 'animate__fadeOutLeft'
};
let transArr = Object.entries(trans).map(e => e[1]);
let aDelay, speed = 'fast' // fast or slow 

$(document).ready(function() {
  // first set up the animations based on our configuration stuff above
  $('.animate__animated').addClass(trans.nextIn) // auto-apply the default IN transition
  if (speed === 'fast') {
    aDelay = 200;
    $('.animate__animated').addClass('animate__faster')
  } else aDelay = 300;

  $(".tab a").click(function() {
    $('.tab').removeClass(transArr); // remove all transition classes from tabs 
    $(`.tab.active`).addClass(trans.nextOut)
    var tabContents = $(this).attr("href");
    $(tabContents).removeClass(transArr)
    setTimeout(() => { // the timeout allows our departing containers a moment to get out before we bring in the next active container
      $(`.tab.active`).removeClass('active')
      $(tabContents).addClass([trans.nextIn, "active"])
    }, aDelay)
  });

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    let currentLevel = $(this).closest('.tab').attr('data-level');
    let prevLevel = parseInt(currentLevel) - 1;
    $('.tab').removeClass(transArr); // remove all transition classes from tabs
    $(`.tab.active`).addClass(trans.prevOut);
    setTimeout(() => { // the timeout allows our departing containers a moment to get out before we bring in the next active container
      $('.tab').removeClass('active')
      let targTab = `.tab[data-level=${prevLevel}]`;
      $(targTab).eq(0).addClass('active ' + trans.prevIn);
    }, aDelay)
  });
});
```

```css
/*CSS for the menu*/
.mobile_background {
  display: block;
  width: 0%;
  height: 0vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.mobile_menu {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

#menu_button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/*CSS for the interactive window*/
.question_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 40rem;
  height: 20rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.yes_part,
.no_part {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.yes_part {
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

a.yes {
  background-color: #FFB8B8;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

a.no {
  background-color: #B1E0FF;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.ticket_type {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.ticket_type a {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.answer_1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.store_place_1,
.store_place_2 {
  display: flex;
}

.store_1,
.store_2,
.store_3,
.store_4,
.store_5 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab.active {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
<!-- The Interactive Window Part -->
<section class="question_wrapper">
  <ul class="tab main-tab active animate__animated " data-level='1'>
    <li class="active">
      <p>Do you have a ticket ?</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="yes_part">
          <img src="yes.png" alt="">
          <a class="yes" href="#tab1">yes</a>
        </div>
        <div class="no_part">
          <img src="no.png" alt="">
          <a class="no" href="#tab2">no</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated " id="tab1" data-level='2'>
    <li>
      <p>Which Ticket do you have ?</p>
      <div class="ticket_type">
        <a href="#tab3">Type 1</a>
        <a href="#tab3">Type 2</a>
        <a href="#tab3">Type 3</a>
        <a href="#tab4">Type 4</a>
        <a href="#tab4">Type 5</a>
        <a href="#tab5">Type 6</a>
      </div>
      <button type="button">Back</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated " id="tab2" data-level='2'>
    <li>
      <p>You can buy the ticket from here.</p>
      <div class="store_place_1">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="store_1">
            <p>Store 1</p>
            <img src="" alt="">
            <p>You need to login first to buy</p>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="store_2">
            <p>Store 2</p>
            <img src="" alt="">
            <p>You need to login first to buy</p>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="store_3">
            <p>Store 3</p>
            <img src="" alt="">
            <p>You need to login first to buy</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="store_place_2">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="store_4">
            <p>Store 4</p>
            <img src="" alt="">
            <p>You need to login first to buy</p>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="store_5">
            <p>Store 5</p>
            <img src="" alt="">
            <p>You need to login first to buy</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <button data-back>Back</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated " id="tab3" data-level='3'>
    <li>
      <div class="answer_1">
        <p>Please go to hall A</p>
        <img src="receptionist.png" alt="">
        <button data-back>Back</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated " id="tab4" data-level='3'>
    <li>
      <p>Please go to hall B</p>
      <button data-back>Back</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="tab animate__animated " id="tab5" data-level='3'>
    <li>
      <p>Please go to hall C</p>
      <button data-back>Back</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<!-- The Menu Button Part -->
<div class="mobile_background" id="menu_background">
  <div class="mobile_menu" id="opened_menu" style="display: none">
    <p>menu 1</p>
    <p>menu 2</p>
  </div>

  <button type="button" name="button" id="menu_button">
      <div class="inner_menu">
        <p>MENU</p>
      </div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI `Object.entries(trans).map(e => e[1]);` is the same as `Object.values(trans)`

Comment: Looking over this reminds me why React and other state management frameworks are so popular ♥

Comment: I believe the issue is that there is an event listener also assigned to all buttons, which your menu button is a button element. You need to make your selector more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is happening because there is another event listener on all button elements that is moving the content any time a button is clicked. To prevent this you can either change the selector that we are attaching the event listener to, or we can add an early exit condition to the event listener.

```js
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    //Prevent from firing if text content has menu
    if (/menu/i.test(this.innerText)) return;

    let currentLevel = $(this).closest('.tab').attr('data-level');
    let prevLevel = parseInt(currentLevel) - 1;
    $('.tab').removeClass(transArr); // remove all transition classes from tabs
    $(`.tab.active`).addClass(trans.prevOut);
    setTimeout(() => { // the timeout allows our departing containers a moment to get out before we bring in the next active container
      $('.tab').removeClass('active')
      let targTab = `.tab[data-level=${prevLevel}]`;
      $(targTab).eq(0).addClass('active ' + trans.prevIn);
    }, aDelay)
  });
```

Keep in mind this means the content element will not move, so you will need to lay your menu over the content with absolute or fixed positioning.

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My idea now is to add a class "back-button" to the whole button and change the JS to 「 $(".back-button").on("click", function() 」. So it will not intefere with the others. What do you think ?

Comment: That is an awesome idea and better than adding an exit condition in my opinion.  good luck